# How to extract all contents inside a div from HTML string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-parsing

I have a HTML string like this :-

```
var html = '<div id="parent_div">
            <div id="child_div">
            <ul>
             <li><img src="wow/img1.jpg" /><a href="http://wow.com">wow link</a></li>
             <li><img src="wow/img2.jpg" /><a href="http://wow.com">wow link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>';
```

How to extract all the contents inside the `<div id="parent_div">` ?

Comment: Is your question about PHP or Javascript? Please use only the relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you could just do `$($html).html();`

In php you could use something like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Andy can we achieve same kind of thing in Prototype JS.Thanks

Comment: @zafar, i'm sure but i don't know how. never tried prototype :)

Answer (score 1):

String is a string. Use a regex to parse it.

On JS side:
Take a look at [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) or [match](http://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp&ei=yGqMTrziB_CL4gTS_-ysCQ&usg=AFQjCNHsd5ZSdXHlmUSuD1lDE1KSdvDpuw)
Something like (not tested):

```
pattern = '/<div id="parent_div">(.*?)<\/div>/';
matches = html.match(pattern);
result= matches[1];
```

This probably doesn't work because it will stop on the first `</div>`, but regex is the way to go here, just find an expression which returns what you need.

Generally I think it is a bad idea to "hardcode" HTML in PHP or JS variables.
IMHO it is better to use a template engine, which can be used on both sides (client and server) like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/). It providers complete separation of HTML from any kind of application logic, client(JS) or server(PHP).

Comment: How replace is going to help ?

Comment: Write a regex that will replace the content with the same content without the top div (opening and closing tags)

Comment: Yes I know. I'm not a big fan of regex, so you will have to find yourself how to write it. Anyway if you have jQuery already use Andys solution. If not you will have to come up with an appropriate regex.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DOM or the other PHP XML libs.

http://se.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: No he can't use that. From his example the html is only in a variable (as a string), not in the DOM

Comment: You can load xml from a variable... http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php

Comment: Ok, true. But is it really worth the effort to load a whole xml from string, just to escape one opening and one closing tag!? Anyway, the question is obviously about javascript

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was faced with the same problem sometime ago, and it had to do with refreshing a div from an ajax result which would return the same page html but now I wanted to grab only the id I wanted, and set the innerHTML. So I wrote a javascript function to do this,

```
    //Extracts all the string or html content from a named div
    function ExtractFromDiv(str_html, str_div_id)
    {


    //The string we want to return at the end
    var str_return = "";  

    //We would copy all the string contents inside a div<div >
    var str_div_contents = "";

    //We need to know where to start the search
    var start_index = -1; 

    //We want to store the length of the string
    var int_str_len = 0; 

    //The array for the beginning of a div
    var arr_div_start = new Array('<', 'd', 'i', 'v', ' ');

    //The array that ends a div
    var arr_div_end =  new Array('<', '/', 'd', 'i', 'v', '>');

    //The ending character
    var char_end = '>';

    //We must put this in the notation ''
    str_div_id =    '\'' + str_div_id + '\'';


    //Lets iterate for all the characters but we start from the first div
    start_index = str_html.indexOf("<div");

    //If we did not find a div then its okay, we just have to return
    if (start_index == -1 ) { return str_return; }

    //We must get the length of the string
    int_str_len = str_html.length;


    // A boolean that we are begininng the search of a div
    var boo_div_start = false;

    //A boolean for the ending tag of a div
    var boo_div_end = false;

    //An integer that keeps count of all the opened divs
    var int_opened_div_count = 0;

    // A boolean that shows if we have found the div with the id
    var boo_div_with_id = false;

    //We are going to loop through and try to get the character
    for(var int_count = start_index; int_count<int_str_len;  int_count++ )
    {

    //This points to the current character we are dealing with
    var char_current = ' ';
    char_current = str_html.charAt(int_count);

    //Lets check the beginning of a div, then the div begins from here
    if ( int_count + 4  <  int_str_len )
    {
       if (   str_html.charAt(int_count)     ==  arr_div_start[0] )
       if (   str_html.charAt(int_count + 1) ==  arr_div_start[1] )
       if (   str_html.charAt(int_count + 2) ==  arr_div_start[2] )
       if (   str_html.charAt(int_count + 3) ==  arr_div_start[3] )
       if (   str_html.charAt(int_count + 4) ==  arr_div_start[4] )

       {
           boo_div_start = true;

          //If we had already discovered the div with the id, then we must count every other div opening and increment it by one 
            if( boo_div_with_id )
            {
              int_opened_div_count = int_opened_div_count + 1;
            }
       }

    }



    //Lets seek 6 characters forward to see if the next 6 characters close a div
    boo_div_end = false;
    if ( int_count + 6 < int_str_len )
    {

       if (   str_html.charAt(int_count + 1) ==  arr_div_end[0] )
       if (   str_html.charAt(int_count + 2) ==  arr_div_end[1] )
       if (   str_html.charAt(int_count + 3) ==  arr_div_end[2] )
       if (   str_html.charAt(int_count + 4) ==  arr_div_end[3] )
       if (   str_html.charAt(int_count + 5) ==  arr_div_end[4] )
       if (   str_html.charAt(int_count + 6) ==  arr_div_end[5] )

           {
                boo_div_end = true;
                //If we had already discovered the div with the id, then we must decrement this by 1
                if( boo_div_with_id )
                {
                  int_opened_div_count = int_opened_div_count - 1;
                } 
           }

    }




    //If we had already discovered the start of a div id we needed then we copy all the content from the start to the end
    //We must also take care of nested divs this means that everytime we reach the beginning of a div we count it as an extra div that must be                      closed.
    //And also when we know the next 6 characters are closing a div we must reduce the number of nested divs!
    //If we had already found the div with the id, then we must copy all thats next
    if ( boo_div_with_id )
    {
        str_return = str_return + char_current;
        //Once we have the opened divs count at zero or less, then we are sure that we copied all the nested divs in between so we are ready to
        //return            
        if ( int_opened_div_count <= 0 ) {  return  str_return;  }

    }



    //The start of div then we must copy the div contents until we reach the end of the div tag >
    if ( boo_div_start )
    {
        str_div_contents = str_div_contents + char_current;
    }
    else
    {
      str_div_contents = "";
    }




    //Now we must detect the end of the div if we had detected the start before
    if ( boo_div_start )
    {
            //The end of the div is denoted by a >
            if( char_current == '>' )
            {
                //We have just copied whats in a div then we must check the id we wanted
                if ( boo_div_with_id == false )
                {
                    boo_div_with_id = ( str_div_contents.indexOf(str_div_id) != -1);

                    // We set this to 1, if we get a new div we increment it by 1 if we get to the end of a div we decrease it by 1
                    int_opened_div_count = 1; 
                }

                str_div_contents = "";
                boo_div_start = false;
            }
    }


    }




    return str_return;
    }


    //U can try this function as follows in your code
    <script language="javascript">

        var sample_html = "";
        var sample_div = "sammy the dog1";
        var sample_read = "";



        sample_html= "<html><body><div id=\'sammy the dog\'><div   id=\'sammy the dog1\'><div id=\'sammy the dog2\'>crap crap</div></div> </div>                               <body></html>";

        sample_read = ExtractFromDiv(sample_html, sample_div);

        alert( sample_read );

    </script>
```

///It works from my end. Good coding!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  var html = '<div id="parent_div">ABC</div>';
  console.log($(html).filter('div').text());
</script>
```

Give this a try!