# How to extract values in quote marks from HTML string?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have the following snippet of code, retrieved from a web page:

```
<li class="player" data-id="168568" data-teamid="156" data-x="142.33" data-y="297.16040000000004" data-name="Corentin Tolisso" data-position="3">Corentin Tolisso<span class="shirt">24</span></li>
```

My goal is to extract "Corentin Tolisso", the shirt number "24" as well as the values of data-x and data-y.

So far I am able to get it to work with values that are within `>...<`, using HTML Agility Pack.

However I can't find a way to extract the numbers of data-x and data-y.

I have copied the HTML string into a new jsfiddle, which puts out exactly what my C# code is getting, the things between `>...<`.

**How do I extract the values of data-x and data-y?**

Note: Using `String.IndexOf` works fine, it takes away flexibility though. This is my fallback strategy.

Note 2: I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520799/how-to-extract-content-from-html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662606/how-to-extract-all-contents-inside-a-div-from-html-string-in-javascript), both of which give me some idea, but I stil have a hard time applying it to C#.

Comment: Those are called attributes.  https://www.google.com/search?q=html+agility+pack+get+attribute+value

Answer (score 0):

1 way would be using `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1`
It supports nested quotes as well

Give it a try to this link:
https://regex101.com/r/cB0kB8/1

With JQuery it makes it very simple.

Also check an example found here: [Getting value of HTML text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808519/getting-value-of-html-text-input)

```
<form name="input" action="handle_email.php" method="post">
Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" value="Newsletter" />
</form> 
<a id="regLink" href="http://mywebsite.com/register?user_email=">Register</a>

$('input[name="email"]').change(function(){
alert($('#regLink').attr('href')+$('input[name="email"]').val());
});
```

Hope it helps you!